# CSS enlarge font animation causing jumpy div

Tags: css

I have added custom CSS for my dev icons

```
.devicon-git-plain:hover{
     max-width: 2em;
}
```

so that the size of the icon increases when I hover over it. But when this happens the div that contains the icons also increases in size. Is there a way to increase the size of the icons without increasing the size of the parent div?

Comment: I think one of the easiest ways to do that is by increasing the size of the parent div! or Absolute Position for the Icon!

Comment: try to use scale for the .devicon-git-plain.
 .devicon-git-plain:hover{transform:scale(1.2); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im thinking that you need to call the hover of the parent div and scale the icon on hover of the parent div.

```
.devicon-git-plain:hover icon{
transform: scale (1.2);
}
icon {
transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tractionworks/k7ofm6vt/3/

Is that what you are going for?